# display nested arrays in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, asmx

I have a json object returned via jquery ajax from an asmx service. When I attempt to display it in a table, nothing displays. What might I be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

The returned json is ...

```
[{\"id\":1488,\"name\":\"Baby Books\",
  \"categories\":
  [{\"id\":152,\"name\":\"Activity Books\",\"value\":\"Ignore\"},
   {\"id\":167,\"name\":\"Bedtime and Dreams\",\"value\":\"Ignore\"}]},
 {\"id\":1489,\"name\":\"Story Books\",
  \"categories\":
  [{\"id\":1506,\"name\":\"Games - Floor Puzzles\",\"value\":\"Ignore\"}]}]
```

the js display code is (where gorupJson is returned from the call) ...

```
var viewModel = {
   groups: ko.observableArray([]), 
};
viewModel.groups(groupJson)
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

the page content is ...

```
<table width="100%" >
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: groups" style="width:100%">
   <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td>
     <ul data-bind="foreach: categories">
      <li>
       <a><span  data-bind="text: name"></span></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not automatically converted into ko collection.
So you need to apply a mapping to this conversion, probably like this ko.mapping.fromJS(data). When you do it, your fields id, name, value will become in ko.observable

If you want to know more about mapping plugin in knockout, take a look at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

First, your JSON is invalid.
Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YNdmh/

```
 var groupJson =  [{"id":1488,"name":"Baby Books","categories":
   [{"id":152,"name":"Activity Books","value":"Ignore"},
   {"id":167,"name":"Bedtime and Dreams","value":"Ignore"}]},
   {"id":1489,"name":"Story Books","categories":
   [{"id":1506,"name":"Games - Floor Puzzles","value":"Ignore"}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing closing tags for `<td>` and `<tr>`

The slashes in json have to go aswell.

http://jsfiddle.net/yhBvr/

Comment: Thanks all ... I've now progressed to a returning json webservice error- ugggh.